# I want to set pickerView to a default value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a multiple pickerViews some are an array and one is a date picker View. I want to set the default value for each to be the first choice. All the picker views have a textField. I know I need to use pickerView.selectRow but I don't know where to call it to work with the textFields automatically.

Here is my code

```
class PillViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

//MARK:- Outlets

@IBOutlet var saveButtonOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var doseTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var typeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var instructionsTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var expirationDateTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var intakeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var colorOrImageTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var pillsCountTextField: UITextField!


//MARK:- Properties

// Selected options
var selectedPillType: String?
var selectedIntake: String?

var userSelectedTimeStart: String?
var userSelectedDateStart: String?
var pillsCount: String?

var selectedNotificationDate: Date?

// Static options
var pillTypes = ["Taps", "Pills", "g", "mg", "mcg"]
var intake = ["1 Times a Day", "2 Times a Day", "3 Times a Day", "4 Times a Day"]
var pillColors : [(colorName: String, color: UIColor)] = [("Red", .red), ("Orange", .orange), ("Magenta", .magenta)]

// Create a new pill NSManagedObject
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

private var datePicker: UIDatePicker?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the interface color of User
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light

    // Check if Required TextFields are not Empty
    checkIfTextFieldIsNotEmpty()

    // Create PickerViews for a textField
    createPickerView(for: [typeTextField, intakeTextField, colorOrImageTextField])

    // Create datePickerView for a textField
    createDatePicker(for: expirationDateTextField)

    // Add toolbar to textFields
    dissmissPickerView(for: [typeTextField, intakeTextField, colorOrImageTextField, expirationDateTextField, nameTextField, instructionsTextField, pillsCountTextField])

    // Add number pad keyboard
    addKeyboardType(textFields: [doseTextField, pillsCountTextField])

}

//MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

//MARK:- UIPickerView data source and delegate methods

// Number of sections
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// Number of dropdown items
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if typeTextField.isFirstResponder {
        return pillTypes.count
    } else if intakeTextField.isFirstResponder {
        return intake.count
    } else if colorOrImageTextField.isFirstResponder {
        return pillColors.count
    }
    return 1
}

// Dropdown items
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if typeTextField.isFirstResponder {
        return pillTypes[row]
    } else if intakeTextField.isFirstResponder {
        return intake[row]
    } else if colorOrImageTextField.isFirstResponder {
        return pillColors[row].colorName
    }
    return ""
}

// Selected item
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if typeTextField.isFirstResponder {
        selectedPillType = pillTypes[row]
        typeTextField.text = selectedPillType
    } else if intakeTextField.isFirstResponder {
        selectedIntake = intake[row]
        intakeTextField.text = selectedIntake
    } else if colorOrImageTextField.isFirstResponder {
        //            pill.selectedColorString = Pill.pillColors[row].colorName
        //            pill.selectedColor = Pill.pillColors[row].color
        //
        //            colorOrImageTextField.text = pill.selectedColorString
        //            colorOrImageTextField.textColor = pill.selectedColor
    }
}

//MARK:- PickerView own methods

func createPickerView(for textFields: [UITextField]) {

    for textField in textFields {
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        textField.inputView = pickerView
    }
}

func dissmissPickerView(for textFields: [UITextField]) {
    let toolBar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.action))
    toolBar.setItems([button], animated: true)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    for textField in textFields {
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
}

@objc func action() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

//MARK:- Own DatePickerView methods

func createDatePicker(for textField: UITextField) {
    datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker?.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    let minDatePicker = Date()
    datePicker?.minimumDate = minDatePicker
    textField.inputView = datePicker
    datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func dateChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {

    // Format date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy, h:mm a"

    if expirationDateTextField.isFirstResponder {

        self.expirationDateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

        guard let expirationTimeText = self.expirationDateTextField.text else { return }

        // Create notification Date
        selectedNotificationDate = dateFormatter.date(from: expirationTimeText)

    }

}

//MARK:- My own methods TextField

func checkIfTextFieldIsNotEmpty() {
    saveButtonOutlet.isEnabled = false
    nameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    doseTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    expirationDateTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)

    tableView.reloadData()
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let nameText = nameTextField.text, let dosageText = doseTextField.text, let startDateText = expirationDateTextField.text else { return }
    if !nameText.isEmpty && !dosageText.isEmpty && !startDateText.isEmpty {
        saveButtonOutlet.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        saveButtonOutlet.isEnabled = false
    }
}

func addKeyboardType(textFields: [UITextField]) {
    for textField in textFields {
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    }
}


//MARK:- Segue Actions

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


    let pill = Pill(context: context)

    // Set pill taken
    pill.pillTaken = false
    let uuidString = UUID()
    pill.uuiString = uuidString

    pill.selectedNotificationDate = selectedNotificationDate

    pill.selectedPillType = selectedPillType
    pill.selectedIntake = selectedIntake
    pill.userSelectedTimeStart = userSelectedTimeStart
    pill.userSelectedDateStart = userSelectedDateStart

    if let destVC = segue.destination as? HomeViewController {

        // Send pill names to HomeVC
        guard let nameText = nameTextField.text else { return }
        pill.pillName = nameText

        // Send pill info to HomeVC
        guard let infoText = instructionsTextField.text else { return }
        pill.pillInstruction = infoText

        // Send pill timer to HomeVC
        guard let userExpirationDate = expirationDateTextField.text else { return }
        pill.userExpirationDate = userExpirationDate

        // Send pill dosage to HomeVc
        guard let doseTextFieldText = doseTextField.text else { return }
        pill.selectedDosage = doseTextFieldText

        // Send pill count to HomeVC
        guard let pillCountText = pillsCountTextField.text else { return }
        pill.pillsCount = pillCountText

        // Send pill color to HomeVC
        //            guard let pillColor = colorOrImageTextField.textColor else { return }
        //            pill.pillColor = pillColor

        // Create Notification
        createNotification(pill: pill)

        // Append new pill to pill array
        destVC.pillsArray.append(pill)

        // Save pills in custom plist
        savePills()

    }

}

//MARK:- Model Manupulation Methods

func savePills() {
    //Save data to Core Data

    do {
        try context.save()

    } catch {
        print("Error Saving context, \(error)")
    }
}

func createNotification (pill: Pill) {

    // Ask for permistion for local notification
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("notification granted!")
        } else {
            print("notification was denied!")
        }
    }

    // Create the notification content
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    // Create notification title, body and info
    guard let pillNameString = pill.pillName else { return }
    content.title = pillNameString
    guard let userExpirationString = pill.userExpirationDate else { return }
    content.body = "Your pill \(pillNameString) expired on \(userExpirationString)"
    content.sound = .default

    // Create notification trigger
    guard let selectedDate = pill.selectedNotificationDate else { return }

    let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: selectedDate)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    // Create the request
    guard let uuidstr = pill.uuiString?.uuidString else { return }

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidstr, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Register the request
    center.add(request) { (error) in
        // Handle error
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to add notification request, \(error!)")
        }
    }

}

}
```

I was able to create all the functions for the textFields and pickerViews separately.

Comment: Are you asking about each individual textField showing the associated data before the user selects anything?

Answer (score 0):

create @objc func and call that func when user taps on textField

use

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(makeTfActive(_:)), for: .editingDidBegin)

    @objc func makeTfActive(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if sender.tag == 0 { //(if u have multiple textFields)
        if(sender.text == nil || sender.text == "") { //mmust check for nil or empty, else it will set first value everytime when user clicks on tf
            sender.text = dataSource[0] //dataSource can be your array of values/object make first value setup here !
        }
    }
}
```